# Any way to reduce pdf file size in mpdf?

Tags: mpdf

I am using mpdf with cakePhp and a pdf about 7 pages and no images is about 5.5MB, how can I have a little size?
Thanks.

The basisc example creates a 5.4MB PDF File

```
$content = "Hola soy el html";
$mpdf = new Mpdf(['format' => 'Letter',]);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($content);
$mpdf->Output("prueba.pdf", \Mpdf\Output\Destination::DOWNLOAD);
```

Comment: Show your code. What are you exactly doing and not doing with mPDF. In short, create a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi.
The basisc example creates a 5.4MB PDF File
     
$content = "Hola soy el html";
$mpdf = new Mpdf(['format' => 'Letter',]);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($content);
$mpdf->Output("prueba.pdf", \Mpdf\Output\Destination::DOWNLOAD); 

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt that is your entire use case, this code example generates about 14kB of PDF with the last mPDF. Provide more information.

Comment: So what coul be the problem... cakephp mpdf plugin version?

Comment: The solution was at the begining of the action in the controller:  $this->autoRender = false; Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

At the action in controller:
$this->autoRender = false;

Comment: Even though it solved your problem, this is not a good answer because it will not help anybody else. It lacks context, explanation why this was happening, and is not even connected to the question, because the question does not describe that this line was used in the first place. Consider updating the question and the answer with more explanation.